# Android Studio conflicting plugin - Which plugin should I use in this case?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, jetbrains-ide

After updating Android Studio to the latest I ran into this bit of problem and a google search provided nothing of value. Apparently I can only use 1 of the 2 markdown (engine?) mechanisms and I have no idea what I have been using all this time.

The below picture is quite self-explanatory:

[image]

I have no idea which one is superior and kind of don't want to spend a whole day find out...

Comment: You do not have to spend whole day on it -- 5 mins will be enough if you have used to edit/view `.md` files before (on regular basis) -- you should have no issue recognizing the plugin interface. But in general: "Markdown Navigator" is most likely what you have used before as AFAIK it's not bundled with the IDE .. so you must have installed it manually.

Comment: Hah I have no collection of installing anything other than clicking "next" all the way through.